# Make Chrome use Firefoxe's Flash

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, browser, youtube

Google chrome is giving me a lot of problems with flash. FLash works fine in firefox. Can I make chrome use the flash player from firefox?

Comment: here you can find flashplayer lib `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so`

Comment: then what? Could you post an answer?

Comment: Which `Chrome` version are you using? The latest version of chrome comes with latest version `Flash`. If you are using some ancient version then update it to latest version.

Comment: i think it is not work for sure , but you can test it
`sudo cp -a /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/lib `

Answer (score 0):

Pepper flash plugin for Chrome:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

Comment: I already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Currently it is possible but it [may not be possible in future versions of Google Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html). For now,

- Type `about:plugins` in the address bar and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Look near the top right of the page that opens for a small blue `+` sign next to the word "Details".
- Toggle that to expand the contents of the page
- Look for `Adobe Flash Player`. You should see **two** versions of the plug-in.
- Disable the one I've highlighted.

From now on, the browser will only use the plug-in you have not disabled.

[image: Two Adobe Flash Player plug-ins]